# python if elif else only returning first output without using logic

Tags: python, django

I have an `if elif else` block that is only producing output for the `if` statement even if it should return the other conditions. Even if I change the order of the conditions it always returns the first one. My code is as shown below:

The `age, education, stability ....` are functions which I defined and I am adding them in `feat_list`

```
class operable:
def __init__(self, f):
    self.f = f
def __call__(self, x):
    return self.f(x)

def op_to_function_op(op):
    def function_op(self, operand):
        def f(x):
            return op(self(x), operand(x))
        return operable(f)
    return function_op

for name, op in [(name, getattr(operator, name)) for name in dir(operator) 
    if "__" in name]:
    try:
        op(1,2)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    else:
        setattr(operable, name, op_to_function_op(op))

@operable
def age(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    age = 0
    if customer.Age == '60 +':
        age = 0
    elif customer.Age == '36 - 59':
        age = 1
    else:
        age = 2
    return age

def education(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    education = 0
    if customer.Education == 'Highschool and below':
        education = 0
    else:
        education = 1
    return education

def employment(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    employment = 0
    if customer.Employment == 'Student':
        employment = 0
    elif customer.Employment == 'Contract':
        employment = 1
    else:
        employment = 2
    return employment

def stability(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    stability = 0
    if customer.Employer_Stability == 'Unstable':
        stability = 0
    else:
        stability = 1
    return stability

def residential(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    residential = 0
    if customer.Residential_Status == 'Rented':
        residential = 0
    else:
        residential = 1
    return residential

def salary(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    salary = 0
    if customer.Salary <= 1000:
        salary = 0
    elif 1000 < customer.Salary <= 10001:
        salary = 1
    else:
        salary = 2
    return salary

def loyalty(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    loyalty = 0
    if customer.Customer_Loyalty <= 2:
        loyalty = 0
    else:
        loyalty = 1
   return loyalty

def balance(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    balance = 0
    if customer.Balance <= 2500:
        balance = 0
    elif 2500 < customer.Balance <= 10001:
        balance = 1
    else:
        balance = 2
    return balance

def feat_list():
    total = age + education + employment + stability + residential + salary 
        + loyalty + balance
return total

for customer in queryset:

    if feat_list() < 12:
        customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 'Silver 
            Package')
        silver_customers.append(customer.Name)

    elif 11 < feat_list() <= 15:
        customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 'Gold 
            Package')
        gold_customers.append(customer.Name)

    else:
         customer.Service_Level = Service.object.get(service_name = 
            "Platinum Package")
         platinum_customers.append(customer.name)
   customer.save()
```

How can I change these statements so that it uses logic not the order?

Comment: You need to explain your problem better, and include what output you expect for certain data.

Comment: Post the `feat_list` too. It may be there's just values < 12?

Comment: Change them from elif and else to just if.

Comment: BTW, you should probably not be calling the function multiple times

Comment: Are you sure you know what `elif` means?

Comment: Please post your feat_list() function

Comment: I have posted my `feat_list()` function

Comment: bro can you check what is being returned in the feat_list(), by printing it?

Comment: @Exprator I have tried printing `feat_list` and I am getting `<function feat_list at 0x7f2cba530938>` in my console. How can I print the actual value?

Comment: store it in a variable and then print the variable like a = feat_list() and do this inside the for loop that you are  running

Comment: @Exprator still getting `<customers.admin.operable instance at 0x7fd3b5f1c1b8>`

Comment: can you give the dictionary for operator that you are using in your code?

Comment: it is actually a list `[(u'Male',
  u'Current Account',
  u'18 - 35',
  u'Tertiary and above',
  u'Student',
  u'Unstable',
  u'Rented',
  454,
  8,
  8721)]`

Answer (score 1):

If you say `feat_list() < 12` dand the value is 11.5, then its true, and execute the firt `if`, but the next condition will be also true `11 < feat_list() <= 15`,
because 11.5, is between 11 and 15.
 My point is... your first condition in your first if, is "containded" in the second condition of the elif:

12 is between 11 and 15, because `11 < 12 <= 15`, so, the first condition is wrong.

Comment: thanks for that, I have rewrote my conditions now starting with `if feat_list() <= 11:` then `elif 11 < feat_list() and feat_list() <= 15:` but I am still getting the second condition as a default

Comment: You have to debbug a little your code (the faster and uglyest wat is put prints), create a list, put some print in the if, elif, and show us what you got. It looks odd to me..

Answer (score 0):

the `elif` will only be evaluated when the if was not true.

So, if you want to check for `11 < feat_list() <= 15:` even if `feat_list() < 12:` is true, use `if` instead of `elif`

Comment: if I use `if` I am now getting the `Gold Packages` by default

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the comparison ranges overlap between Silver and Gold packages (11-12). Also, you probably don't want the Platinum package to be the "default" one (without check, provided it is the highest level). Maybe it would be more clear what the code is doing if you rewrote the comparison in the following style (pseudocode):

```
flist = feat_list()
# You can check the returned value here, ie. print(flist), and the value
# won't change before you're finished with the comparison.

if flist > 15:
    #...Platinum processing...
elif flist > 11:
    #...Gold processing...
else:
    #...Silver processing...
```